# Special characters serilazation in rest services in json representation

Tags: json, rest, serialization, cxf

Hi i am facing a problem while serializing the special characters.I need to display Norweign characters.I need to display TÅRNPLASS but it is serializing as TÃ…RNPLASS.Can anyone help me regarding this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To show the output in the correct way you have to set the Content-type for your response. It's just a starting poin but I can't help you in other ways because you didn't add more information about your specific problem.

Comment: hi kamy22 thanks for response.Can you please tell should be the content type for Ã type of characters.In specific how can i serialize norwegian characters in response

Comment: You have to use the utf-8 encoding.